# RegEx that doesnt allow tilde / console key

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex

```
(^[a-zA-z]+([a-zA-Z\s-]*)[a-zA-z]+$)
```

It disallow all special chars except ( ` ) the console key.
Could someone explain what im doing wrong in my regex or how i can remove that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `[A-z]`, use `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z\s-]*)[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Otherwise, the `[A-z]` class will match some other non-letter symbols, too:

[image]

Here is a [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aJ1mS1/1).

Just a note: `[A-z]` can sometimes be used to match all letters in POSIX-style regex when collation is set for a particular language.

`[[ "ABCEDEF[]_abcdef" =~ ([A-z]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` on Cygwin with `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` yields `ABCEDF`.
If you set `LC_COLLATE` to `C` (on Cygwin, done with `export`), it will give the expected `ABCEDEF[]_abcdef`.